# How I will store image folder path into the MYSQL Database and display the image in a webpage via PHP and XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysqli

My image path in C:\xampp\htdocs\leadstart\Bestleads\landing\Health\new\img\logo.png

My Database
imgid,companyid,cimage1

I want to insert above image path to cimage1 and display that image in my webpage via PHP

and my PHP code

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query1 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT cimage.cimgid,cimage.companyID,cimage.cimg1 FROM cimage where companyID=$id");

        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {

         <?php 
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row2['cimg1'] ).'"/>'; ?>

                            ?><!-- Displaying Data Read From Database -->


                            <?php
                }
            }


  ?>
```

Comment: I hope you are storing base64 encoded data on the database. You should not have to store base64 on the database. Instead of it, you could have store the image path on the table. For example, while you are uploading the image move the image into your desired folder and calculate your absolute image path and store it on the table. in this way, you should not have to store the encoded image in the table as a string.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example?

Comment: Did you check on w3schools? Because I can't describe better than that

Comment: If you are facing any problems just feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you upload image,you must save this image to a folder in your project directory and then save this path to your database
for example your path is:  C:\xampp\htdocs\leadstart\Bestleads\landing\Health\new\img\logo.png

save logo.png to your database and when you need to view this

```
    <?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query1 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT cimage.cimgid,cimage.companyID,cimage.cimg1 FROM cimage where companyID=$id");
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
?>
       <img src="http://127.0.0.1/leadstart/Bestleads/landin/Health/new/img/<?php echo $row2['cimg1'] ?> "/>
        <!-- Displaying Data Read From Database -->
        <?php
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Image not displayed. I store logo.png in cimg1 and cimg1 type is varchar

Comment: image stored in your project directory?

Comment: only you need that save 'image name' in your database

Comment: Yes. I save logo.png in the database

Comment: Full texts 
cimgid
companyID
cimg1

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
1
12003
logo.png

Comment: are you sure this address is correct ?   http://127.0.0.1/leadstart/Bestleads/landin/Health/new/img/$row2['cimg1']

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\leadstart\Bestleads\landing\Health\new\img\logo.png

Comment: enter this address on your browser: http://127.0.0.1\leadstart\Bestleads\landing\Health\new\img\logo.png ,

Comment: picture is displayed

Comment: ok, echo this address on your php file  echo "http://127.0.0.1/leadstart/Bestleads/landin/Health/new/img/'.$row2['cimg1'].'"; and then check that address is correct or not?

Comment: echo "127.0.0.1/leadstart/Bestleads/landin/Health/new/img/$row2['cimg1]"/>;

Comment: I use this echo '<img src="127.0.0.1/leadstart/Bestleads/landin/Health/new/img/$row2['cimg1'] "/>';

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\leadstart\Bestleads\landing\Health\new\healthdetails.php on line 175

Comment: Not displayed the image

Comment: please give me your full code again. not displayed?? :| :|

Comment: Now it is displayed.Thank You